# Jakarta Regexp 1.5 Backreferences?

Tags: java, backreference, regex

Why does this match:

```
String str = "099.9 102.2" + (char) 0x0D;
RE re = new RE("^([0-9]{3}.[0-9]) ([0-9]{3}.[0-9])\r$");        
System.out.println(re.match(str));
```

But this does not:

```
String str = "099.9 102.2" + (char) 0x0D;   
RE re = new RE("^([0-9]{3}.[0-9]) \1\r$");      
System.out.println(re.match(str));
```

The back references don't seem to be working... What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try it with this target string:

```
"099.9 099.9\r"
```

A back-reference doesn't mean *execute that subexpression again*, it means *match another instance of whatever that subexpression matched*.

You also have to use two backslashes in the back-reference:

```
RE re = new RE("^([0-9]{3}.[0-9]) \\1\r$");
```